# Angular dynamic form display added inputs in added order

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I'm trying to make a dynamic form in which a user could add any number of input in any order to the form. From all the examples I found, this is the closest one ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-xcychx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-form.component.html)).

Here is a image of what I'm trying to achieve.
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmW27.jpg)

Sum up I'm struggling in:
 1. How can I add a button specific input in a row.(one input at a time not a group as in demo) 
 example(lastname>firstname>lastname>number). 
 2. If the input is a duplicate. How to push both values into an array.(example if the form has 2 lastname inputs with different values in it. Both inputs should be used as unique ones so they wouldn't overwrite one another when Submit is pressed).

Comment: For checking duplicate input, you can check this example of Stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nt5agm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, but i'm looking for a demo that would have both these problems solved. Because when I manage to make one work the other one fails.